# QR code scanner javascript module running without HTTPS/Secure connection

Tags: javascript, qr-code

Right now I develop an app to scan QR Code. But the problem is every JS module I knew like `instascan.min.js` or `jsQR.js` is need to run on secure connection or HTTPS request.

it blown my mind because it is developed for local server usage so the domain is using `weird IP address` which don't have SSL certificate that chrome thinks it's dangerous so the JS module can't run perfectly.

What should I do?

Comment: I'd recommend getting a proper domain and an SSL certificate with it, browsers block camera access unless its served from `localhost` or over SSL

Comment: but it's only used on intranet and not public, any idea about that?

Comment: @CerebralFart or maybe can you please give me a link to generate SSL only for local? because I've tried generate SSL but it says "windows doesn't have enough information to verify this certificate"

Comment: Your browser won't know the difference between the internet and an intranet, so it will block it regardless. You can create your own root certificate and install that in your machines, but that may be too much effort. Alternatively, you can use let's encrypt for a free SSL certificate. Check letsencrypt.org for more info on how that works.

Answer (score 0):

for the problem to open camera it's magically solved by [this](https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/enabling-the-microphone-camera-in-chrome-for-local-unsecure-origins-9c90c3149339). it's simple tho!